# Sklearn LogisticRegression equation clarification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Just wanted to sanity check myself here.

After fitting a LogisticRegression model I can call model.coef_ and model.intercept_ in order to construct the equation, correct?

For example, let's say we fit a model with features A & B. When model.coef_ is called, are the coefficients returned in the same order?

If:

```
model.coef_ = [0.25, 0.11]
model.intercept_ = 5.5
```

Then our formula would be:

```
(0.25*A) + (0.11*B) + 5.5
```

Hopefully this post won't require more than a 'yup, you got it', but I'd appreciate any clarification if I missed anything important.

Comment: That is correct. This will be then passed through a sigmoid function to generate a probability.

Answer (score 0):

Those estimated coefficients are plugged into the logistic function to get a prediction. The formula would look something like:

probability=1/(1+exp(-(5.5+(0.25*A)+(0.11*B))))

Comment: The equation gives a number to pass to a sigmoid function, which gives the probability score. Gotcha, thanks!